# django json query working in shell but not views

Tags: python, django, json, django-views, simplejson

in my views I am running a query that extracts information based on previous kwargs passed.

Sample paypaladaptive debug.request entry

```
{"returnUrl": "http://localhost:5000/paypal/return/pre/30/75f946df1bef45598cd42c45ff9e5e1c/", "maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments": "100.00", "maxNumberOfPaymentsPerPeriod": 1, "startingDate": "2012-03-30T07:59:09.447420", "maxNumberOfPayments": 1, "currencyCode": "USD", "endingDate": "2012-06-28T12:59:09.447158", "project": 585, "ipnNotificationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/paypal/ipn/30/75f946df1bef45598cd42c45ff9e5e1c/", "cancelUrl": "http://localhost:5000/paypal/cancel/pre/30/", "pinType": "NOT_REQUIRED", "requestEnvelope": {"errorLanguage": "en_US"}}

from django.utils import simplejson as json
from paypaladaptive.models import Preapproval

@login_required
@require_GET
def cancel_preapproval_bulk(request, project_id):
    preapprovals_list = []
    preapprovals = Preapproval.objects.all().exclude(preapproval_key=None).exclude(status='canceled').exclude(status='used')
    for obj in preapprovals:
        json_object = json.loads(obj.debug_request)
        if json_object['project'] == project_id:
            preapprovals_list.append(obj)

    print preapprovals_list
```

When running this execution through django shell you get a list generated according to the args passed, ie the project id.

When running this in a normal django view it return an empty list...

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you're importing Preapproval and also look into the use of [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) on a QuerySet so you can use it as a dictionary.

```
{"returnUrl": "http://localhost:5000/paypal/return/pre/30/75f946df1bef45598cd42c45ff9e5e1c/", "maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments": "100.00", "maxNumberOfPaymentsPerPeriod": 1, "startingDate": "2012-03-30T07:59:09.447420", "maxNumberOfPayments": 1, "currencyCode": "USD", "endingDate": "2012-06-28T12:59:09.447158", "project": 585, "ipnNotificationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/paypal/ipn/30/75f946df1bef45598cd42c45ff9e5e1c/", "cancelUrl": "http://localhost:5000/paypal/cancel/pre/30/", "pinType": "NOT_REQUIRED", "requestEnvelope": {"errorLanguage": "en_US"}}

from project.app.model import Preapproval

@login_required
@require_GET
def cancel_preapproval_bulk(request, project_id):
    preapprovals_list = []
    preapprovals = Preapproval.objects.all().exclude(preapproval_key=None).exclude(status='canceled').exclude(status='used').values()
    for obj in preapprovals:
        if obj['project'] == project_id:
            preapprovals_list.append(obj)

    print preapprovals_list
```

---

EDIT: Should have refreshed the page *facepalm*. Still, you should look into values().

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with the items nested inside the debug_request, if you execute obj['status'] it works, but not obj['project'] since it lies in obj['debug_request'] so how do I go one level deeper?

Comment: I've never tried that, but the docs say: "Returns a ValuesQuerySet — a QuerySet subclass that returns dictionaries when used as an iterable, rather than model-instance objects." so I guess it should work...